# How to detect multiple classes in one image where no object is an option

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

Lets say I have data-set of images of roads, I want it to out put an array with each element ranges from 0-1. First 0-1 nothing in the image, secondly 0-1 if there is a car and finally 0-1 if there is a bike. There could be both a bike and a car in the image. My labels are labeled as such [1,0,0] if there is nothing and [0,1,1] if it has both a car and a bike.

I don't car about the coordinate of the car or the bike. I used vgg16 and my last layer output 3 outputs with sigmoid function. I'm stuck in the loss function. I made a custom one but I believe my use of squared difference is wrong, here is my custom function.

```
def lf(y_true,y_pred):
    square=0
    batchsize=25
    for i in range(batchsize):
        if y_true[i,0]==0: 

            square+= tf.squared_difference(y_true[i,0:3], y_pred[i,0:3])
        else:
            square+= tf.squared_difference(y_true[i,0], y_pred[i,0])





    mean_square= square/batchsize
    return mean_square
```

So if there no object(y_true[0]=1) then guessing car or bike doesn't matter and I only take loss for the first part y_true[0]. Is this the right method or should I do binary cross entropy. My loss is stuck at 0.24605921 for a while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem you are trying to solve it's called multi-label multi-class image classification.
In this case squared differences doesn't make sense. Since you are using Keras you can use inbuilt loss function [binary_crossentropy](https://keras.io/losses/#binary_crossentropy).
I would also suggest you keep only two elements in ground truth labels i.e [0,0] first for car and second for bike. If model predicts [0,0] then there is nothing in image. No need to keep third label for no object in this case.